# CountDownTimer runs in old Activity when switching Activities

Tags: android

I have a CountDownTimer, which needs to run all the time. There are 2 Activities (A and B). Activity A has the CountDownTimer, which updates a TextView inside it. When I switch to B, the CountDownTimer still runs (it is the desired behavoir), but when I switch back to A, there seems to be an old and a new A. The timer does not update a TextView inside of the "new" A. It is started only once when A is first visited. Any ideas of how to solve this problem? Maybe put the timer somewhere else?
**Edit:** Some code:

```
private void prepareTimer() {
    // TODO: DOES NOT WORK YET! (switching activities -> runs in old activity)
    textTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_time); // is a field

    if (!timerRunning) {
        timerRunning = true;

        int duration = 60000;
        timer = new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long minsLeft = (long) Math.floor((double) millisUntilFinished / (double) Constants.ONE_MINUTE) + 1;
                textTime.setText(minsLeft + " Min.");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                textTime.setText("done!");
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, you should learn more about your activities lifecycle... When coming back from B to A make sure you have stuffs in onStart(...) method.

Answer (score 0):

`CDT` is running in its own separate thread. The `TextView` reference you are trying to access, in that `CDT` is no longer usable (because your activity A was no longer visible while you was in B) try to create new reference that `TextView` when you return to A. The `CDT` thread was still running regardless you have moved from A to B or viceversa. I hope this will help. Make sure you do changes in UI thread. ;)

Edit:

```
private void prepareTimer() {
    // TODO: DOES NOT WORK YET! (switching activities -> runs in old activity)
    textTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_time); // is a field

    if (!timerRunning) {
        timerRunning = true;

        int duration = 60000;
        timer = new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long minsLeft = (long) Math.floor((double) millisUntilFinished / (double) Constants.ONE_MINUTE) + 1;
                textTime.setText(minsLeft + " Min.");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                textTime.setText("done!");
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
    else
    {
     textTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_time);
    }

}
```

Comment: But how do I tell the timer to use the new reference? Currently, the timer updates the TextView inside the `onTick()` method. I update my first post with the code to make it clear.

Comment: Do `if(MyActivity.this!=null && textTime==null) textTime = MyActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.mytxt);` inside `onTick()`

Comment: It didn't work. `textTime` never becomes `null` and when I call `prepareTimer()` the second time, when switching from B to A again, the new `textTime` is a different Object. The Old timer keeps updating the old one.

Comment: Just read your edit. The `else` branch probably won't help. The problem is, that after switching to B, `textTime` does not become `null`. It seems that, after switching back from B to A, there are two As. The timer just updates the old `textTime`, but I don't know why there even is one. Before switching from A to B I call `finish()` on A. Any ideas?

Comment: `Intent launchActivityAIntent = new Intent(mainActivity, A.class);
startActivityForResult(launchActivityAIntent, 0);
finish();`.  
The `mainActivity` is the starting Activity. I keep it for the Context.

Comment: Addition: There is probably no second A, but i'm still confused why `textTime` won't become `null`

Comment: Probably there is some referencing problem. I guess I just stop the timer in A, give the remainig time to B, and do the same when switching from B to A.